# Searching for a neat proof

Tags: inequality

I'm searching for a neat solution for the following exercise: << Prove that:
$$\forall a,n\in \mathbb{N^*}:\,((a\leq n \, \, \wedge 0\leq50-a\leq100-n)\Rightarrow \, \frac{a}{n}+\frac{50-a}{100-n}\leq \frac{148}{99})  $$

and determine for which couples $(a,n)$ equality holds.>>

Actually I solved the exercise, but I didn't manage to find a solution which does not use derivatives, so an elementary one.

My solution is the following:

Let's call $f(a,n)$ the expression contained in the LHS of the inequality. Since $f(a,n)=f(50-a,100-b)$ with $50-a,\, 100-n$ respecting the same conditions on $a$ and $n$, we can say WLOG $\,\,\,n\leq 50$.

Let's consider the function $g: \, [0,1]\times \{n\in \mathbb{N^*}\vert \,\, n\leq 50\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$g(x,n)=x+\frac{50-nx}{100-n}$$

Then

$$\frac{\partial g(x,n)}{\partial x}=1-\frac{n}{100-n}=\frac{100-2n}{100-n}\geq 0$$

and so, fixed the value of $n$, the maximum value of $g(x,n)$ is reached only when $x=1$. So the maximum value of $g(x,n)$ is reached when $$1+\frac{50-n}{100-n}$$ is maximum, and so only when $n=1$. So the maximum value of $g(x,n)$ is $1+49/99=148/99$. Noticing that $g(a/n,n)=f(a,n)$, we obtain that
$$f(a,n)\leq \frac{148}{99}$$
with the equality if and only if $(a,n)=\{(1,1),(99,99)\}$.

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: How do you define a "simpler solution", or a "neat proof"?

Comment: A simpler solution is a solution which does not use derivatives or analysis in general.

Comment: Please edit your post to define "simpler solutions", and also define "neat proof", as stated in your title.

Comment: Ok, but now I'm going to attend a lesson. When I turn home I'll edit the post.

Comment: It's okay, I've edited your post given your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equivalent to finding the maximum of $\frac an + \frac bm$ with the constraint $a+b=50, n+m=100, a\leqslant n, b\leqslant m$.

BTW I believe your condition should be $1\leqslant n \leqslant 99$.

Since $100=2\times 50$, $\min (\frac an, \frac bm) \leqslant \frac{1}{2} \leqslant \max (\frac an, \frac bm)$. WLOG assume $\frac an \leqslant \frac bm$.

If $\frac an = \frac bm$ then both are exactly one half, the sum is 1.

If $\frac an < \frac 12 < \frac bm$, $2a < n, n\geqslant 2a+1, a\leqslant 49$, then

$$
\frac an \leqslant \frac{a}{2a+1}=\frac 12 \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2a+1}\right) \leqslant \frac 12 \left( 1- \frac{1}{99}\right)=\frac{49}{99}.
$$

(basically it means the largest integer fraction less than one half, with denominator not exceeding 100, is 49/99.)

and
$$
\frac bm \leqslant 1.
$$

When $a=49, n=99$, both inequalities become equality simultaneously.

Therefore $\frac an + \frac bm \leqslant \frac{49}{99}+1 = \frac{148}{99}. \blacksquare$